# How to edit .woff font files offered by Google Webfonts?

Tags: fonts, google-webfonts, woff, woff2

Is there any free or cheap editor for Windows, that would allow to edit files with .woff extension (I checked in css that the font file has woff extension). These are fonts offered by Google Webfonts and they are free to embed, modify etc. I'd like to only add diacritic accents to some letters for specific language and embed the font on a website.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Convert the 'woff' webfont to a regular font (e.g. TTF) using a service such as [Online Font Converter](http://onlinefontconverter.com/). Then edit the converted file with your favorite [font editing software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_editor).

Specific 'woff' Editor:

http://www.high-logic.com/font-editor/fontcreator.html

Programming Tools:

http://www.freetype.org/

Comment: Google brought me here I suppose

Comment: Google brought me here, (*goes uses Google again, ends up here again*).  -_-"

Answer (score 19):

There's a free, cross-platform tool called **FontForge**, which can be used to create, edit, and view a wide array of font types.

**Homepage**: http://fontforge.org/
**Github**: https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/

Here are some screenshots of it in action:

#### WOFF

[image]

#### WOFF2 <sup>([added in 2018](https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/issues/1503))</sup>

[image: Woff2 Character Map]

#### Editing Characters

[image: Editing Characters]

Comment: Fontforge can't handle woff2 fonts.

Comment: @peterh this is no longer true. It seems to handle woff2 files just fine now

Comment: @Brad I am not sure what specific formats it can handle, but anything I throw at it in woff format won't even open, let alone be edited.

Comment: @astralmaster, the latest version should handle .woff and .woff2 just fine.  If you're having a specific issue, I'd open an issue on the github repo, but every file I've tested has worked so far.

Comment: Can confirm, this software does not open my *.woff2, while a web tool like eg [this one](http://fontstore.baidu.com/static/editor/index-en.html) does so without complaining.